# Firebase UserEmail all the time verified

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why is the user email verified all the time?

I do not know why the user email still verifying and reload function return true even when I do not verify the email, but i receive mail.

```
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:my_chat_app/View/pages/home.page.dart";
import "package:my_chat_app/View/pages/login.page.dart";

void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBKZ_8PVfbb_VwHw4P8yTMcFOH6zoM_oZE",
            appId: "1:36434956024:android:60204da7a7e7c1877a750d",
            messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
            projectId: "chat-app-27389"),
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    Future<bool> reload(User user) async {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.reload();
        return user.emailVerified;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: user != null && reload(user) == true
              ? const HomePage()
              : LoginPage());
  }
}
```

This is the implementation of the sign in/up method:

When the user press login  button :

```
MyBotton(
  btnText: "Login",
  onTap: () {
    reload();
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      firebaseServices!.loginWithEmailPassword(
          emailController.text,
          passwordController.text,
          context);
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the sign-in methods used. if the user uses Google sign-in, then emailVerified will always return true, if that is not the case then provide the code that shows the sign-in methods implemented. Also, could you take out your apiKey from the post or any public view... that is dangerous

Comment: Plese check the code I modified it I added the sign in methode

Comment: Try this method instead on A Stream builder, 


FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()

This is what I use on my project and it works fine. except you use Firebase admin to modify the state on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Your `reload` is an asynchronous method that returns `Future<bool>`. That means that `reload(user) == true` should not even compile in this code:

```
home: user != null && reload(user) == true
  ? const HomePage()
  : LoginPage());
```

If you want to use a `Future` while building a UI, you need to [use a `FutureBuilder`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEdw_1B7JHY).

Comment: My probleem is note the future but Whene I check if the user email is Verified I find that is verified all the time

Comment: The code from your question that I included in my answer shouldn't even compile as far as I can see. Are you saying this code compiles? Or do you mean we should not be looking at this code (in which case: it probably shouldn't be in your question)? I recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example